# FTP proxy that translates from passive to active

Tags: windows, ftp

Is it possible to install a proxy server that will transform passive ftp to active ftp?

Details of my problem: I would like to deploy my web sites using Visual Studio's built in publish web site function. The problem is that my web hotel only supports active ftp, and unfortunately Visual Studio 2010 has a bug, so the publish function only works with passive ftp. My idear is to install a tiny local ftp proxy, that is able to transform passive ftp mode to active mode. I would then enter localhost as the publish server in Visual Studio, and the proxy would do the actual uploading of the files to my web hotel.

Visual Studio bug report: [Unable to publish website to FTP server that doesn't allow passive mode](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/321202/unable-to-publish-website-to-ftp-server-that-doesnt-allow-passive-mode).